# Loading module from was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”)

Tags: javascript, python, mime-types, simplehttpserver

I am going through a three.js example and when I use `import` within a javascript module I get the error:
`Loading module from “http://localhost:8000/build/three.module.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”).`

When I import traditionally using a script tag I do not get this error. Here is my code:

Commented out lines will render a rotating cube

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';
            // const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            // const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            // const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            // renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            // const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
            // const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            // const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            // scene.add( cube );

            // camera.position.z = 5;

            // const animate = function () {
            //  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            //  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            //  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

            //  renderer.render( scene, camera );
            // };

            // animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In contrast, this works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="build/three.js"></script>
        <script>
        // ...
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My file structure is:

```
|_index.html
|_ ...
|_build/
    |_ three.module.js
    |_ three.js
    |_ ...
```

Why do i get the MIME-type error when using `import` in a module? I would like to be able to use this import method because all the other three.js examples seem to do this in JS modules.

Comment: What http server are you running to serve these files?

Comment: With Python 2.7, I am running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the root directory

Comment: Did you try to load with real relative path with a `.` before  path `'./build/three.module.js';?
 `

Comment: You need to fix that server to send the proper content type header for your javascript files. See e.g. https://ericduran.io/2017/10/09/js-modules-python-mime-type/

Comment: @Bergi But `.js` is already a known mime-type according to the link you provided.

Comment: Somehow your server doesn't seem to send any though

Comment: ack the `.` before the path seemed to do it... so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error message `Loading module from “http://localhost:8080/build/three.module.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”).` when I start my http server in the `three_js/examples/` folder.  Starting the http-server in `three_js/` fixes the problem.  The reason is that the import statement for me was `import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';`.   I'm not sure this solves your exact problem, but it seems closely related.

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me, thank you.